# Hover depends on font-size in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

**What I'm trying...**

I'm trying to make a menu with a hover effect. If you hover a link, it's background-color should change. If you go to the next one, it should change smoothly to the next link.

---

**Problem**

When you hover over one link and then go to the next one, there is a small gap between the elements. If your mouse is at that exact spot, nothing happens.

---

**Working Example**

```css
.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

a {
  padding: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href='#'>Menü #1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href='#'>Menü #2</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href='#'>Menü #3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Not Working Example**

```css
.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

a {
  padding: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href='#'>Menü #1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href='#'>Menü #2</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href='#'>Menü #3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**My observation**

If you change the `font-size` just by one pixel, it works. If I use IE it works in both examples, but in Chrome only the Working One works :D

---

**What I'm asking for...**

Is this a Chrome bug or is there a possibility to make the 'not working one' work.

Comment: This is a very interesting snippet - I've explained the issue in my answer, but in short, it's basically because of the built in display property of the `a` tag coupled with some default styling in the chrome browser. Well spotted. And +1 for a very well written question.

Comment: My upvote to a very nice question

Comment: Both works fine here in Chrome 57 and Opera 44 on macOS. Did the examples change or is this an issue with older Chrome versions?

Comment: @OptimusCrime I can still replicate the issue on my Chrome - if you'd like some clarification, on the second example, there's a single line (1px width) in between the two `a` tags that shoudn't be there. The `a` tags need to be directly next to each other.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's actually an interesting question. The "issue" is caused by the browser CSS that is reading the `display:inline;` of the `a` tag, and not having it fill the entire `display:block;` of the `li` tag.

You can fix this by using the following CSS rule

```
.menu-item a {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: That's not a bug, is the expected and desired result. Inline elements works as this. Don't say that's a bug because is not.

Comment: Hi @MarcosPérezGude - Thanks for the feedback :) I didn't mention anything about it being a bug - not sure where the confusion is from, because I agree that it's not a bug? Hence my explanation of the default styling...

Comment: Oh my God! Sorry for my misunderstood. I read `You can fix this bug...` and your write `You can fix this by...`, so much sorry for the confusion. I need to come back to reading lessons on the school. Maybe that my native language is not english... :(

Answer (score 8):

Add `display: block` to the links. The link is smaller than the li

Answer (score -5):

Remove the font-size and line-height from the menu-item, style the link directly. This behaviour most likely comes from rounding errors.